# validate directory path

Tags: ruby, directory, dir

I'm writing a backup program in Ruby.
The user enters the destination directory.

How do i validate the entry?
When i intentionally enter something silly like a/:mcjhs, I keep getting an error. (of course lol)

How do i stop this from happening?

Thanks for your help :-)

edit:

this is a sample of what i mean:
destination1 cannot be created and throws an error. how do I pick up on that beforehand?

```
destination1 = 'hj&:test1'
destination = 'f:\test'
if (test(?d,destination1))
    puts "already exists"
    system "pause"
else 
    Dir.mkdir(destination1)
end
```

I solved it, and yes i did research before too :-P

i put the if statement into a begin/rescue/end statement. so easy. thanks for your help!

```
begin
destination1 = 'hj&:test1'
destination = 'f:\test' 
if (test(?d,destination1))
    puts "already exists"
    system "pause" 
else 
    Dir.mkdir(destination1)
end
rescue
    puts "error"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `if/else`?

```
if File.directory?(destination)
  ....
else
  ....
end
```

Comment: i've been using (test(?d,destination)) with if/else statements, yes.
the problem is to check if the value the user entered is a possible/valid directory name.
if i ask if it is a directory, it comes back false because it does not exist yet.

Comment: why don't you edit your question and show what you have done (ie your code) , and what went wrong and what you expect to see as correct.